# Unable to access .dll with ctypes with python 3.3+

Tags: memory, ctypes

I stumbled upon a problem when I upgraded my python 3.2 installation to 3.3+. I am searching for a solution for a while now and couldn't find anything.

I am using a .dll to use a hyphenation algorithm that was implemented using Delphi. 
The .dll is working with all python version below version 3.3. When I try to access it with python 3.3+

I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Python34\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 351, in __init__
self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 998] Invalid access to memory location
```

I call the dll like this

```
hyph = windll.syllable

hyphenInput = 'testen'

#Set the input parameter
input_string = c_wchar_p(hyphenInput)     
ShowDividing = c_bool(True)
ShowRootVowels = c_bool(True)
Sprechsilben = c_bool(True)
PrefixAsMorpheme = c_bool(False)

exception = c_wchar_p('')

hyph.DivideOnSyllables.restype = c_wchar_p
hyphenation = hyph.DivideOnSyllables(input_string, ShowDividing, ShowRootVowels, Sprechsilben, PrefixAsMorpheme, exception)
```

Hope someone can help me out here.

Thank you in advance.

EDIT 1:

I got the DLL from someone else. The header information I got, look like this:

```
function DivideOnSyllables(Input: PWideChar;
     ShowDividing,ShowRootVowels,
     Sprechsilben,PrefixAsMorpheme: Boolean;
     Exceptions: PWideChar): PWideChar;
```

EDIT 2:

It seems like the call to open the DLL (WinDLL('syllable')) is already producing the error.

Comment: Test a module that loads a system DLL, e.g. `psapi = WinDLL('psapi')`.

Comment: Also, on an unrelated tangent, show the prototype for `DivideOnSyllables`, because what you're doing with `exception` looks odd. Also you can pass `hyphenInput` and the `True` and `False` values directly; there's no need for `c_wchar_p` and `c_bool` there.

Comment: The system DLL is working. I added the header information I got. Do you need more information? And if so, it would be great if you could point me to how to gather them.

Comment: Are you sure it's finding the right DLL on the system `PATH`? Try an absolute path, e.g. `WinDLL(r"C:\Path\To\syllable.dll")`.

Comment: Back on the unrelated tangent, how is `Exceptions` used? Is it supposed to be a buffer for an error message?